# C4800: 'float': forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false' (performance warning)

Tags: c++

I know this question has been asked before, but I didn't find any promising answers, and the cases were different from mine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>

template<class getN>
getN getNum(std::string prompt, std::function<bool(getN)> condition, std::string error)
{
    std::cerr << prompt;
std::string strNum;
std::getline(std::cin, strNum);

try
{
    size_t pos;
    getN num;

    if (std::is_integral<getN>::value == true)
    {
        num = static_cast<getN>(stoi(strNum, std::addressof(pos)));
    }
    else
    {
        num = static_cast<getN>(stof(strNum, std::addressof(pos)));
    }

    if (all_of(strNum.begin() + pos, strNum.end(), [](char c) { return isspace(c); }) && condition(num))
    {
        return num;
    }
}
catch (std::exception) {}

std::cerr << error;
return getNum(prompt, condition, error);
}

void fillArray(float *arr, int size)
{
    std::cout << "\nFill the array:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "arr[" << i + 1 << "]=";
        arr[i] = getNum<float>("", [](bool num) {return num != 0.0f; }, "Bad input! Try again: ");
    }
}

int main()
{
    int size;
    std::cout << "Size: ";
    std::cin >> size;

    float *arr = new float[size];

    fillArray(arr, size);

    delete[] arr;

    std::cin.ignore();
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Calling the function with an "int" like the very last statement, doesn't give me any errors or warnings, but calling it with "float" like the fillArray function throws the C4800 at me.

Comment: You are implicitly converting a `float` value to a `bool`, hence the warning. Try `return num != 0.0f`.

Comment: If you mean `return num != 0`, why not say so? Or ignore the warning, it's fairly silly.

Comment: "C4800" sounds like some compiler-specific error code. Please include the actual error message in your question. (Apparently it's [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6801kcy.aspx)).

Comment: I've rolled back your two recent edits. (1) The way to indicate that your problem is solved is to accept an answer. (2) Updating the code in your question to a version that fixes the problem *destroys the question*, since it's no longer clear what you're asking. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141749/167210

Comment: Ahh, sorry :P It's the first time I post something here. I'll have it in mind in the future, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared your `getNum` function:

```
getN getNum(std::string prompt, std::function<bool(getN)> condition, std::string error)
```

to take a function of that returns a `bool` value from `condition`.

And then call it with this:

```
arr[i] = getNum<float>("", [](float num) {return num; }, "Bad input! Try again: ");
```

which passes a `float` return value. Whilst the compiler CAN convert a `float` to a `bool`, it is not as efficient as taking the `bool` return value from the function. So use:

```
[](float num) -> bool {return num != 0.0f; }
```

instead, it should not complain.

Also, in future, it would be better to produce a COMPLETE program that can be compiled (that is, has all the `#include` required, as well as the `main` function to exercise the code), that way someone can JUST take your code, compile it and make some slight changes to fix the problem, rather than having to guess what headers are required and how you intend the things you posted to be used.

Comment: Ahh sorry, it's cause the complete program was quite huge, I engineered a smaller one and edited it in the original post. 
Thanks for you answer, although even after I use

  `arr[i] = getNum<float>("", [](bool num) {return num != 0.0f; }, "Bad input! Try again: ");`

I still get the warning

Comment: That's not what I said to use... `bool` and `num != 0.0f;` is what you need.

Comment: Yes, I use that too, it's in the code above.
`insert code here` ok now i know how to input code lol

Comment: Sorry, I put `bool` in the wrong place. I will edit. You need to make clear that the return value is `bool`, and that input is `float`.

Comment: Hmm, that is something I haven't seen before. But it works like a charm. So as I understand it... `[](float num) -> bool` just specifies the return type of the function?

Comment: Yes, in lambda functions `-> T` will specify return type of `T`.